# Bootstrap accordion run function before opening

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

Is there any way to run some function before and accordion it's fully opened?

Here's the code:

```
            $.each($('.accordion-toggle'),function(){
                $(this).click(function() {
                    if($(this).hasClass("collapsed")){
                         //loading content via ajax
                    };
                });
```

I tried to use `.on('show')` functions and changing `data-toggle` with javascript opening and closing content, but it seems to be very complicated due to existing code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
$.each($('.accordion-toggle'),function(){
      $(this).click(function() {
            if($(this).hasClass("collapsed")){
                \\loading content via ajax
            }
      });
});
```

You forget the ";"...

Comment: Yeah, didnt copied one line of code, but that's not what my problem is.